# Adding duplicate rows together, with different conditions for different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

My df looks something like this (very simplified):

| Name | Age | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 27 | 12 | 17 | 13 |
| David | 23 | 14 | 50 | 10 |
| John | 27 | 4 | 19 | 7 |
| David | 23 | 10 | 8 | 12 |

Essentially the problem I have is that I want to merge the rows with duplicate names (i.e. same person). The age would stay the same, columns A and B need to be added together but for column C I must average the two values.

I have tried:

`df.agg({'A' : ['sum'], 'B' : ['sum'], 'C': ['mean']})`, but this just creates a new df with those column values.

I'm quite inexperienced with pandas so I have only tried a limited amount of things.

I would like the result to be like so:

| Name | Age | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 27 | 16 | 36 | 10 |
| David | 23 | 24 | 58 | 11 |

In reality I have many more columns, (over 100). I have created lists of the column names which need to be added, averaged and then kept the same.

My main idea was to do something such as:

```
do_nothing = [] #lists contain column names already
add_cols = []
avg_cols = []

for i in df.columns:
 if i in do_nothing:
    #dont do anything
 if i in add_cols:
    #add cols
 if i in avg_cols:
    #get mean
```

If I only needed one operation e.g. 'sum' I know I could just do:
`print(df.groupby(["Name", "Age"], as_index=False).sum())`, but I am unsure how to do this with multiple operations using the column lists described above.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group your data by name and then add aggregation for different columns:

```
(df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'Age': 'first', 'A': sum, 'B': sum, 'C': 'mean'})
)
```

**Output:**

```
     Name  Age   A   B     C
0    John   27  16  36  10.0
1   David   23  24  58  11.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Managed to work out the column list issue too based on your solution. In case it helps anybody else I did: res = (df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({**{dn : 'first' for dn in do_nothing}, **{addcol : 'sum' for addcol in add_cols}, **{avcol: 'mean' for avcol in avg_cols}})
)